# Deciding between resetting and rolling back

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently, I have had to use SourceTree. Every time I realize I have to undo stuff after a commit (or after a few commits) and just go back to the state of the project at a certain revision, I assume that I can simply roll back because I use git (via SourceTree) but when I double-click on a commit to check it out and take it from there, I always get a warning message that this action would create a **detached head**, etc...

I have seen a lot of posts that deal with hard resetting, etc... but I wonder how would one just **roll back** without causing problems such as detached head then, and not having to reset all the previous commits?

The best option I could come up with was to do:

```
$ git checkout -b <branchName> <commitId>
```

which would create a new branch that only has up through the specified commit.

However, the following also seems to be doing what I want:

```
$ git reset <commitId>
```

My understanding is that the two are really the same. Are they?

What advantages each might have? I would love to hear from senior developers who have been using git for a long time, so I can learn something that you have discovered after a few years along the way...

Comment: You should read the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). The operations you describe are different concepts (creating a branch, checking out a commit, resetting) and they have different results.

Comment: No, they are not the same. Learn and practise the skills of `git-rebase`. It can solve many of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two commands give different results.

To see the differences between `git checkout -b <branchName> <commitId>` and `git reset <commitId>` the best thing is to experiment. Create a new empty directoy and run the following commands:

(Initialisation, common scenario)

```
# Common commit
git init
echo a > a; git add .; git commit -m"a"
echo b > b; git add .; git commit -m"b"
```

(Checkout)

```
git checkout -b branch1 HEAD~1
```

Result: We have created a new branch named branch1 and switched to it. This new branch contain only the first commit. The branch master is intact.

(Reset)

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

Result:
    We stay on branch master, the last commit is removed but its content stay in the working directory.

In conclusion, we can say that in both case we see the same commit logs. But in the case of  `git checkout -b <branchName> <commitId>` we create a new branch, and in the case of `git reset HEAD~1` we stay on the same branch and keep the same content in the working directory.